# WindowBuilder not show Design tab when migrating using zip

Tags: eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I designed an Swing application using **WindowBuilder Pro** and I need to migrate to another computer.  So I zipped the project (from local **git** folder) and imported in the new computer.  However, when I right click the file and select *Open With* **WindowBuilder**, it is like a normal file, without the design tab.  However, I am able to new a **WindowBuilder** file.  So is there anything went missing when I migrate?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I wouldn't migrate systems by zipping my projects and copying them, but rather set up a GitHub repository or something similar and clone all my projects.

But in your case:

1. Check if both of your Eclipse and Java version are on par with your old machine.
2. From your explanation I could not really understand HOW you exported and imported your project, but make sure you got everything correct! (Import process in particular!)
3. When right-clicking the class that you want to open in the WindowBuilder design view go to "Open With" > "WindowBuilder Editor".